# Installing Applaud in eclipse

Tags: applaud

I am trying to install the Applaud plugin in Eclipse Kepler but for some reason the installation is not completing. 
The installer is stuck on 48 percent for some time and seems to be downloading the same file over and over again. Any Idea whats causing this problem?